# busybox and nfs mounts

Tags: nfs, busybox, system-recovery

As part of a startup a rescuecd uses busybox to mount a nfs share with data, but during the nfs share mount, busybox (version v1.18.2 from systemrescuecd) always **fails** to mount the nfs share. And i do not find the reason why, because when using an alternative it works

```
mount -o intr,nolock,rsize=1024,wsize=1024 192.168.0.3:/rescue /boot 
mount: mounting 192.168.0.3:/rescue on /boot failed: Connection timeout

# On the serverside 
>> authenticated mount request from 192.168.0.69:642 for /rescue
```

But here comes the mystery, when i use the following command on the same busybox commandline the nfs mount works (and the server message does **NOT** appear).

```
mount.nfs 192.168.0.3:/rescue /boot -o intr,nolock,rsize=1024,wsize=1024

# This works and it is mounted.
```

What is the difference, who can i make the "normal" mount work on busybox (which is a symlink to busybox)

Otherwise i have to modify the systemrescuecd to make it work. but maybe there is a nfs server tweak just to accept whatever busybox tries to accomplish.

EDIT: 
Found out that the mount command is succesful, when the **"tcp"** option is added.

```
mount -o intr,nolock,rsize=1024,wsize=1024,tcp 192.168.0.3:/rescue /boot
```

So the question is more now, why does the mount fail with the "udp" option

```
mount -o intr,nolock,rsize=1024,wsize=1024,udp 192.168.0.3:/rescue /boot
```

I am lost here.

Comment: Is your `iptables` configuration identical in both situations?

Comment: yes it is the very same commandline. Busybox drops after faiure into the commandlline. First command (original one) fails, the second succeeds. I have a further data point, added above

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable the nfs server to listen on udp port. This is option `-u` (see also: `man nfsd`).